# Java Split String and Combine

Tags: java, combinations

I would like to split a string and combine them.

```
String value = "1,A 2,B 3,C"
```

outputs

```
[1,2 A,B]
[1,3 A,C]
[2,3 B,C]
```

If I do `String[] tokens = value.split("[,\\s]+");`
`tokens[0] = "1"` `tokens[1] = "A"` `tokens[2] = "2"` `tokens[3] = "B"` and so on.
But then how can I combine it that becomes the output? Thank you.

Comment: It's not very clear what you requirement is here. Do you want all possible permutations, for example, should the output include `[1,3 B,C]` or `[1,2 A,C]`? If not, why not?

Comment: @DaveyDaveDave `[1,3 B,C]` or `[1,2 A,C]` are not required. because `1,A` `2,B` `3,C` is a pair. so `A` should not combine with `C` if `1` combines with `2`

Comment: I see, so @Satya's comment will be a good start, split on the space first (`value.split("\\s")`), then you have the pairs you want, and then you can split again on the comma, and pair up appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

You can split and combine it by doing this:

```
String a = value.charAt(0)+","+value.charAt(4)+" "+value.charAt(2)+","+value.charAt(6);
String b = value.charAt(0)+","+value.charAt(8)+" "+value.charAt(2)+","+value.charAt(10);
String c = value.charAt(4)+","+value.charAt(8)+" "+value.charAt(6)+","+value.charAt(10);
```

Comment: with this method, it is hard coding it. and the above is just an example. For what I need to do, the string lengths varies as I am reading it from a text file.